# Angular CLI SCSS Source Maps with Safari?

Tags: css, angular, safari, sass, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 app with Angular CLI 1.0.3.  I have it configured to use `scss` as the `styleExt`.

I run the app with `ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss -o`

In Chrome 60, if I inspect an element, the styles correctly map to the originating scss file.

**However**, in Safari (any version, but most recently 10.1 and Tech Preview 33) the styles just point to `styles.bundle.css` — NOT to the mapped source scss.

At the bottom of `styles.bundle.css` in either Chrome or Safari I see

`/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.bundle.css.map*/`

I see no such actual file in my `client` directory though, although as I said Chrome somehow works.  Why won't it work in Safari?  Am I missing something obvious?